# windows cmd command - syntax error

Tags: syntax, cmd, robocopy

i'm getting error when running this command:

```
for /f "delims=|" %f in ('dir /b y:\db\b') do "Y:\robocopy.exe" "y:\db\b\%f\" "y:\db\a\%f\Certificates and deliverables\" /e

"Y:\robocopy.exe" "y:\db\b\a 001\" "y:\db\a\a 001\Certificates and deliverables\" /e

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows     ::     Version XP010
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Tue Mar 15 14:06:41 2011

   Source : y:\db\b\a 001" y:\db\a\a\
     Dest : y:\db\b\001\Certificates\

    Files : and
            deliverables"

  Options : /S /E /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2011/03/15 14:06:41 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory y:\db\b\a 001" y:\db\a\a\
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

i cannot seem to get it work, help pls.

Answer (score 0):

When parsing the command line, some commands treat `\"` as an escaped `"`.

You should double your backslash.

Also see [This reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx) regarding the MSVCRT (a dependency walker shows robocopy uses the MSVCRT).

Let me suggest:

```
for /f "delims=|" %f in ('dir /b y:\db\b') do "Y:\robocopy.exe" "y:\db\b\%f\\" "y:\db\a\%f\Certificates and deliverables\" /e
```

Comment: @Andre: I admit that this is really tricky… here is a sample command line to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the fact that a double-quote preceded by a backslash is interpreted as an escaped double-quote... sometimes.

See this article by Raymond Chen: [What's up with the strange treatment of quotation marks and backslashes by CommandLineToArgvW](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/09/17/10063629.aspx)